# What's a lightweight way to synchronize CLIPBOARD -> PRIMARY selections?

Tags: linux, command-line, clipboard

My use-case is that I want that whenever I copy something to CLIPBOARD, it is also saved in PRIMARY. It's mostly assumed that to copy something you need to select it so most of the time this is not needed.

However, sometimes I just click the classic "copy to clipboard" button and get something to CLIPBOARD that it's not in PRIMARY. I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> a lot for pasting and having to track which selection I'm using makes me confused.

I know there are a tools like `clipit` or `parcellite` that do something like this, but I wan't something without a GUI, something like a simple `systemd` service I can launch and forget.

I tried using a `systemd` service for `autocutsel` configured like

```
ExecStartPre=autocutsel -f
ExecStart=autocutsel -f --selection PRIMARY
```

However this also synchronizes PRIMARY -> CLIPBOARD, which breaks some very usual workflow like selecting text and then replacing it with the contents of the clipboard.

I've looked for this option in the manpage of `autocutsel`, but I find it kinda confusing, with a lot of mentions to `cutbuffer` (which I don't think it's used anymore) and Windows which I don't use. So I don't even know if this is possible with `autocutsel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick Python program to do so, using the PyGObject bindings for GTK. I'm not an expert in this, so this is just an example that works for me, using  rpm pygobject2 on an old Fedora release. You will have to find the equivalent packages yourself.

```Python
#!/usr/bin/python3
# copy clipboard to primary every time it changes
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/660344/119298
import signal, gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

# callback with args (Gtk.Clipboard, Gdk.EventOwnerChange)
def onchange(cb, event): 
    text = clipboard.wait_for_text() # convert contents to text in utf8
    primary.set_text(text, -1) # -1 to auto set length

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL) # allow ^C to kill
primary = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY)
clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
clipboard.connect('owner-change', onchange) # ask for events
Gtk.main() # loop forever
```

Comment: Python is not really lightweight in my book, but your solution is simple and short enough